# Можно ли как-то вытащить конструкцию группировки из результата поиска регулярного выражения?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Собственно говоря код

```
const char *first = "фывфыв@NameOfElement(pupa i lupa)вфывфыв"; 
const char *last = first + strlen(first);

cmatch mr; 
regex rx("@NameOfElement\((.*?)\)"); 

    regex_search(first, last, mr, rx);


cout << mr.str();
```

Вывод выглядит так: @NameOfElement

насколько я понимаю регулярные выражения (а делаю я это плохо), то конструкция вида

```
  (.*?)
```

это так называема capturing group, которая в моей регулярке соответствует тексту внутри скобок аннотации, могу ли я каким-либо образом выудить ее из результатов поиска?

Comment: Во-первых тут проблема с экранирующими `\ ` , `\(`  должно быть `\\(` и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать `.str(1)` объекта типа `cmatch` (или `smatch`):

```
const char *first = "фывфыв@NameOfElement(pupa i lupa)вфывфыв"; 
const char *last = first + strlen(first);
cmatch mr; 
regex rx(R"(@NameOfElement\((.*?)\))"); 
regex_search(first, last, mr, rx);
cout << mr.str(1); // => pupa i lupa
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/JvBmis).

Я использовал *raw string literal*, `R"(@NameOfElement\((.*?)\))"`, это эквивалент `"@NameOfElement\\((.*?)\\)"`. Кстати, лучше заменить `.*?` на `[^)]*` или `[^()]*` (=ноль и более символов, отличных от `)` / `(`).